# Hello World jQuery DataTable example. Sort icons are a bit off

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I would imagine this could be easily reproduced in a few steps:

Using Visual Studio 2015, I created a new web project using the ASP.NET MVC template. I then installed jquery.datatables into my ASP.NET MVC project.

```
Install-Package jquery.datatables
1.10.11
```

And modified the generated index.cshtml in the Home view folder to see if I could get the Data Table to work.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


<table class="table table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document)
            .ready(function () {
                $('.table').dataTable();
            });
    </script>

}
```

I added the needed css and js references to my master page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML table turns into a DataTable, but the sort icons look kind of weird. This is how they should look. I found this:
[image: Should look like]

But instead mine look off:
[image]

I have this big semi transparent "down arrow with 3 lines to the right" next to the up down arrows that I expected.

I can't seem to make sense of the CSS.

Comment: try to remove `jquery.dataTables.css` linkage.

Comment: Good guess, I expected it to work, but no, same result. I thought it might have bootstrap and jquery styling competing.

Comment: I removed the bootstrap css instead and it looks like the expected arrows. I'm not sure if I understand the bootstrap icons. The arrows always points down although I understand how the lines change. feel free to post your response which was very close and I'll mark it the answer. thank you!

Comment: **If you want to use boostrap theme**:
did you load the css in bootstrap package which is from http://getbootstrap.com/. I have the same problem before when i forget to load the bootstrap package.I do not know that your issues which is cause by same reason or not?

Comment: I did. And when the Bootstrap css is used instead, it works just like this example, https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html, when the arrow is always pointing down. I dont understand how this is desirable. I do understand the text lines that change. I guess teh arrow reads "the items below" are sorted in the order indicated by the "lines"

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that `/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css` (only v3) is adding extra `::content` of type Glyphicons Halflings on top of the "native" arrows. This gives the effect with for example a black `glyphicon-indent-left` (I believe it is in unicode `\e150`) next to a blue indicator.

Personally I dislike it, it took some time to figure out (I am using angular) but cannot understand why it should be necessary to enrich the bootstrap styling with something completely new.

You can neutralize the extra icons by adding this CSS `after` your inclusion of `dataTables.bootstrap.css` :

```css
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after {
    content: "";
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after {
    content: "";
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after {
    content: "";
}
```

Then the good old sorting icons appears, and only them.

You could also leave out `dataTables.bootstrap.css` completely (but not `dataTables.bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.min.css`) I do that myself in some projects, and it does not really make that difference. Many of the tweaks in `dataTables.bootstrap.css` is what most people would already have in their CSS - like giving headers a pointer cursor, disabling bootstraps exaggarated margins and so on.